# Installing Landscape on Ubuntu Server 22.10

Tags: 22.10, landscape

Trying to add the Landscape repository but constantly getting this error:

```
michael@naples:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:landscape/self-hosted-23.03
[sudo] password for michael:
Repository: 'deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/landscape/self-hosted-23.03/ubuntu/ kinetic main'
Description:
Dependencies for Landscape Self-Hosted release version 23.03.
More info: https://launchpad.net/~landscape/+archive/ubuntu/self-hosted-23.03
Adding repository.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Found existing deb entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/landscape-ubuntu-self-hosted-23_03-kinetic.list
Adding deb entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/landscape-ubuntu-self-hosted-23_03-kinetic.list
Found existing deb-src entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/landscape-ubuntu-self-hosted-23_03-kinetic.list
Adding disabled deb-src entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/landscape-ubuntu-self-hosted-23_03-kinetic.list
Adding key to /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/landscape-ubuntu-self-hosted-23_03.gpg with fingerprint 35F77D63B5CEC106C577ED856E85A86E4652B4E6
Ign:1 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/landscape/19.10/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Ign:2 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/landscape/self-hosted-23.03/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Hit:3 http://mt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Hit:4 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/landscape/self-hosted-beta/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Get:5 http://mt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates InRelease [118 kB]
Err:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/landscape/19.10/ubuntu kinetic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Err:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/landscape/self-hosted-23.03/ubuntu kinetic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Get:8 http://mt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports InRelease [99.9 kB]
Get:9 http://mt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security InRelease [109 kB]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/landscape/19.10/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/landscape/self-hosted-23.03/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 0):

Landscape-server is supported on only a limited set of ubuntu versions (usually 1, sometimes 2 to allow upgrading), all of which are usually Ubuntu LTS (long term support) versions. 22.10 is not an LTS release.

Try installing on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
This is mentioned in the landscape-server documentation, now apparently located at https://ubuntu.com/landscape/docs/self-hosted-landscape

landscape-client, on the other had, should be installable on any ubuntu versions.